# Making one list from two lists by grouping them in a special way

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
list1 = {{{x1,x2},{x3,x4}}, {{x5,x6},{x7,x8}}};
list2 = {{{x9,x10},{x11,x12}}, {{x13,x14},{x15,x16}}}
```

I need to join them to get one list:

```
 {{{x1,x2},{x3,x4},{x9,x10},{x11,x12}}, {{x5,x6},{x7,x8},{x13,x14},{x15,x16}}}
```

There is a Join[] function that seem like a good choice to solve this problem but I can't apply it in a right way to get the appropriate result. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Join` with level specification `2`:

```
Join[list1, list2, 2]
```

> {{{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}, {x9, x10}, {x11, x12}}, {{x5, x6}, {x7, 
>      x8}, {x13, x14}, {x15, x16}}}

Answer (score 6):

```
MapThread[Join, {list1, list2}]
```

> {{{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}, {x9, x10}, {x11, x12}}, {{x5, x6}, {x7, 
>      x8}, {x13, x14}, {x15, x16}}}

Comment: I think this works in older versions of Mathematica (pre V10)

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[{list1, list2}, {2, 1, 3}]
```

> {{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}, {x9, x10}, {x11, x12}, {x5, x6}, {x7, x8}, {x13, x14}, {x15, x16}}